# Text getting progressively smaller in the distance

Tags: edit-mode

I want to extrude text getting smaller in the distance.  How to do this ?  Extrude text property does not seem to permit getting the text smaller.

Comment: Can you put an example screenshot? I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the text this way you would need to convert it to a mesh.

In *Object Mode* press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> this brings up the convert popup, select *Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*.

Having the text object converted change to *Edit Mode* and extrude it manually <kbd>E</kbd> and scale <kbd>S</kbd> as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a *Solidify* modifier instead of the extrude setting for the text object, then you can have text that is thinner father away (that tapers).

1. Add the *Solidify* modifier to the text object.
2. Add a Lattice object around the text (scale it in object mode to fit the text)
3. After the Solidify modifier add a *Lattice* modifier to the text and put in the name of the new lattice.
4. in edit mode, edit the lattice so the text tapers the way you want.